# Nodejs multiple sse request

Tags: node.js, mqtt, server-sent-events, nodejs-stream

I have multiple sse streams which can be accessed using a token. I need to keep all streams open and update the response coming from the streams to the database. I tried one stream with http module as mentioned in link 
https://medium.com/@moinism/using-nodejs-for-uni-directional-event-streaming-sse-c80538e6e82e

And it works fine but I don't know how to keep multiple streams open and how to differentiate streams? There is also mqtt stream available but that too I have the same question.

I expect an on data function which is kept open and keeps streaming from various sources with an ID to differentiate.